# ngrx store angular 2 refreshes the store on page refresh

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

I am using ngrx store v.4.x.x, currently i am storing an user in the local storage as well as ngrx store. Once storing an object to local storage i am populting my  ngrx store. And later in subsequent pages i using ngrx store for data evaluation. But storing in local storage is causing exposure of sensitive object info.

Without local storage when i use ngrx store for evaluation on page refresh the entire store gets refreshed. How to maintain ngrx store state on page refresh withou any storage in angular 2.??

Any help will be appreciated......

Comment: you cannot once a hard refresh is done data is lost from the store you cannot do anything on this you have to use a combination of local storage and ngrx store for this approach

Comment: How can we detect a hard refresh is done in angular 2?? is there any method for hard refresh ?

Comment: hard refresh is browser refresh button

Comment: that i know hard refresh is button but what i mean is that is there any way to detect hard refresh event is fired up an we can catch that event